# javascript, how cookies work in Chrome and blogger?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

javascript, how cookies work in Chrome and blogger?

I know there are many such questions, but this is only not work in chrome and for a blog found on Blogger.

firefox in my code works perfectly.

I'm trying to display a message or perform an action only once within three minutes for example.

In this code I just want a message the first time the blog "Daddy" visit is displayed.

After 3 minutes if recharge or visit another page in the blog message seen again.

Firefox is running and no chrome.

Can anyone tell me I'm wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function GetCookie(name) {
  var arg=name+"=";
  var alen=arg.length;
  var clen=document.cookie.length;
  var i=0;
  while (i<clen) {
    var j=i+alen;
    if (document.cookie.substring(i,j)==arg)
      return "aqui";
    i=document.cookie.indexOf(" ",i)+1;
    if (i==0) break;
  }
  return null;
}
var visit=GetCookie("yyyy");
if (visit==null){
   alert("papi");
   var expire=new Date();
   expire=new Date(expire.getTime()+30000);
   document.cookie="yyyy=aqui; expires="+expire;
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: You really ought to explain in words what you're trying to accomplish and what problem you see with your current code.  Just dropping a block of code here with no explanation of the problem is requires us to try to guess what you're trying to do and will not attract nearly as many answers as a completely clear question that describes the problem clearly in words.

Comment: debug it and figure out what is going on. console.log is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

That are slight differences between browsers, that can cause strange errors. To deal with this, I suggest you to use a framework like jquery, that has a plugin for manage cookies.